# Pandas - fill a new column with a single value, based on .loc value within dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, fillna, pandas-loc

I have a DataFrame with a list of returns data. One row in the DataFrame contains the return for the benchmark, 'ASX', which in this example has a value of 6. (Values are updated using market data, so will change day to day, the below is for simplicity).

Example DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

IDs = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'ASX']
Returns = [5, 7, 10, 6]

data = {'ID': ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'ASX'],
        'Ret': [5, 7, 10, 6]}

frame = pd.DataFrame(data)

bmk = frame.loc[frame['ID'] == ('ASX'), 'Ret']

frame['Rel Ret'] = frame['Ret'] - bmk
frame
```

The current output looks like this:

```
    ID  Ret Rel Ret
0   ABC 5   NaN
1   DEF 7   NaN
2   GHI 10  NaN
3   ASX 6   0.0
```

My problem is, I want to fill the whole column 'Rel Ret' with the value in Ret column minus 'bmk', i.e. I want to return values -1 (5-6), 1 (7-6), 4 (10-6), 0 (6-6). How do I do for the entire column?

Answer (score 1):

Your `bmk` is a *Series* object, when you subtract two pandas Series, their index are aligned, so only rows at same index are subtracted. If you are sure you have one value in `bmk`, you can extract the value using `.iat[0]` and then subtract with it, in which case, you are subtracting a scalar from a *Series* object and the calculation would be broadcasted to every element in the Series:

```
frame['Rel Ret'] = frame['Ret'] - bmk.iat[0]
frame
#    ID  Ret  Rel Ret
#0  ABC    5       -1
#1  DEF    7        1
#2  GHI   10        4
#3  ASX    6        0
```

Comment: Thank you @Psidom, works perfectly. I hadn't come across .iat before.